# Передать из формы (autocomplete) id

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Здравствуйте. Есть функционал заполнения формы. Всё работает. После заполнения поля и отправки на сервер, мне нужно чтобы метод `Voyager` принимал `Id` моих моделей, а не имена. Если `{value = a.Id, label = a.Name}`. То это приводит к тому что в выпадающем списке отображается список имён, а при выборе - Id.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <h2>Выбор маршрута</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Voyager", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="nameBusStopStart" class="form-control" placeholder="Начальный пункт" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("AutocompleteBusStopStart", "Main")'>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

---

**Model**

```
public class BusStopViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteBusStopStart(string term)
{
    var models = _busStopRepository.AutocompliteBusStopStartRepo(term).Select(a=>new{value = a.Name, label = a.Name, id = a.Id});

    return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

**AutocompliteBusStopStartRepo()**

```
public IQueryable<BusStop> AutocompliteBusStopStartRepo(string nameBusStop)
{
    var names =
        db.BusStops.Where(p => p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(nameProduct.ToUpper()));
    return names;

}
```

---

**jquery-ui**

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Так в этом и смысл этих ключей, что label - это то, что пишется в dropdownlist, а value - то, что подставляется в input и отправляется в запросе

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky  Это понятно. И выглядит на пальцах это так: ввожу пару букв - > вылетает dropdownlist с "названиями" (например остановок) - > выбираю из списка например "Москва" (пусть ID у неё заведомо будет 12). И мне нужно чтобы в input(е) отображалось название моей остановки - "Москва". А отображается "12". Зачем это пользователю и видеть и знать? Так вот хотелось бы добиться чтобы в input(е) было название остановки, а в метод, после отправки формы приходил id. Если и label и value присвоить "name" всё работает красиво, но соответственно и в метод летит name.

Comment: P.S. Вытягивать в [POST] методе Id по Name - не вариант. Не та стоит задача.